# Empty values in recordset

Tags: php, database, recordset

I'm trying to get data from my database - here's my code:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from u_gui where nam='".$nam."'",$db);
$total = mysql_num_rows($rs); // returns 1
if(!$total)
{
    echo "no records found.";
}
echo $rs["data"];
```

When I'm fetching the record works I'm getting 1 from mysql_num_rows() but when trying to echo the actual data i'm always getting blank results .. :(

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Would you please show structure of table `u_gui` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result returned by [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is a ressource, in order to get the data from that ressource you need to call [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or other `mysql_` function that can parse that ressource.

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from u_gui where nam='" . mysql_real_escape_string($nam) . "'",$db);
$total = mysql_num_rows($rs);

if(!$total)
{
    echo "no records found.";
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $row["data"];
```

On a side note, when you put non-sanitized data directly in a query (in your case `$nam`) make sure you apply [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to that variable before. Otherwise if your string contains character like `'` it can produce sql error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($total == 0)
{
    echo "no records found.";
}
print_r $rs;
```

and make sure you are connected...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you better understand:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from u_gui where nam='".$nam."'",$db);
$total = mysql_num_rows($rs); // returns 1

if($total > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {   
            echo "$key = $value<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```